# Does the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury’s fire damage work on the Armorer Artificer’s Thunder Gauntlets?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, stacking, artificer

Does the extra 1d6 fire damage to “grasped” weapons granted by the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury effect the Thunder Gauntlets from the Armorer Artificer subclass if the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury are the Thunder Gauntlets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel like it should work, because the gauntlets say that they cause magical flames to envelop one or two melee weapons in your grasp (as opposed to a weapon your holding with the gauntlet) and because when you make a fist the thunder gauntlets are themselves in your grasp of your actual fleshy hands. If the gauntlets specified that they worked on a weapon that you’re holding with the gauntlet, then I could see how it wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

## Not as written

The wording for Thunder Gauntlets that are a part of the Armorer Alchemist's Guardian Armor model state:

> Each of the armor’s gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon **while you aren’t holding anything in it** and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on a hit.

The "and it deals 1d8 thunder damage" clause only applies when the gauntlets are used as simple melee weapons, which they only count as when no other items (not just weapons) are held.

So as soon as the Alchemist holds *anything* in a hand, that hand's gauntlet can't benefit from Thunder Gauntlet.

Meanwhile, Gauntlets of Flaming Fury from Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus state:

> While you wear both of these steel gauntlets, any non-magical weapon you grasp with either gauntlet is treated as a magic weapon. As a bonus action, you can use the gauntlets to cause magical flames to envelop one or two melee weapons in your grasp. Each flaming weapon deals an extra 1d6 fire damage on a hit.

So the Gauntlets essentially ignite whatever weapon they are being used to hold. However, because Thunder Gauntlets require that the Alchemist *not* be holding anything in them, you have an either-or, but not both situation.

---

User Medix points out that it is possible to bring this whole issue to a grinding halt even before this. The line of reasoning goes something like this:

Armor Model's Thunder Gauntlets relates to the Arcane Armor feature. That feature states:

> As an action, you can turn a suit of armor you are wearing into Arcane Armor

It is possible to parse this to mean that only complete suits of armor may be made into Arcane Armor. If part of that suit is replaced, the replaced component is not able to benefit from any features of Arcane Armor that the part it replaced could benefit from.

In other words, because Gauntlets of Flaming Fury are standalone gauntlets and not part of a larger suit of armor, they can't be used with with any gauntlet-related features of Arcane Armor.

I personally think that puts players in a terrible position where they have to choose between class features and magic items. Magic items are meant to be attractive character upgrades.

Moreover, the rules for Arcane armor state "Your metallurgical pursuits have led to you making armor a conduit for your magic" I think that's sufficient textual support for a DM to rule that an Artificer is clever enough to figure out how to incorporate magical armor into a larger suit. As Tim Gunn might say: *Make it work, Artificers.*

Comment: It may be worth addressing whether the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury can even *be* used as Thunder Gauntlets in the first place or whether the Arcane Armor always has its own, different gauntlets

Comment: If gauntlets of ogre strength can be the thunder gauntlets as is commonly assumed then I don’t see why not

Comment: @Rykara but if the gauntlets are grasping themselves then there’s still nothing being held with the gauntlets. Otherwise the Thunder Gauntlets would always be holding themselves and would never work in any situation

Comment: @Michelle If your DM rules that a 2-handed smash attack prevents the use of Thunder Gauntlets, something, somewhere, has gone horribly wrong ;-)

Comment: @MichelleSims Is there some text somewhere which suggests/claims Gauntlets of Ogre Strength are valid for thunder gauntlets? It might then be helpful for the second part of this answer.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Since a “suit of armor” is an undefined game term then the common meaning should apply, and I don’t think the common meaning implies that all the pieces of armor must come from the same forged set.

Comment: @Rykara what if you grasped the wrist of one of your gauntlets while attacking with the grasped gauntlet? It would sorta look funny but I don’t see anything prohibiting it

Comment: Scale armor is also called a suit though and it lacks boots or a helmet, so it would seem to me that just because plate armor is described as a suit of armor does not necessarily mean that it defines what a suit of armor is

Comment: @michelle I think that's an issue of semantics ("Am I holding my gauntlet or am I grabbing my arm?") and not the rules themselves. If you can convince your DM to let you wield yourself, more power to you. It wouldn't happen at my table.

Comment: The "you can't wear the Flaming Gauntlets while you have Arcane Armor active" stance is a pretty big stretch IMO.

Comment: @rev I agree, but I included it because, if one user thought it might be valid, others as well.